# What did Harry Potter include in his interview with The Quibbler?

Tags: harry-potter

What exactly were the contents of the interview? Did Harry reveal the dual cores his and Voldemort's wands share? If not how did he explain his escape? As far as I'm aware he never reveals this to anyone.

Before the interview he maintained the lie that Cedric was killed by Voldemort not Wormtail. Did he reveal how Wormtail killed Cedric? If not how did he explain how Voldemort did it before he regained a body? Did he describe Voldemort regaining his body at all?

Comment: Since Wormtail killed Cedric at Voldemort's command ("Kill the spare"), it seems a bit unfair to call Harry's account a lie. Voldemort was responsible for Cedric's murder even if he didn't carry it out by his own hand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Everything he could remember.

> Harry had not found it an easy experience to talk about the night when Voldemort had returned. Rita had pressed him for every little detail and **he had given her everything he could remember**, knowing that this was his one big opportunity to tell the world the truth.
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 26, Seen and Unforseen)*.</sub>

Presumably this would include details about the twin cores and Cedric's death. We're not given details of what featured in the final article so can't be sure of what exactly Harry remembered or forgot, and which details Rita (or Xenophilius Lovegood) cast aside in the editing process. Nevertheless, the excerpt above indicated that it was an exhaustive interview and that Rita wanted to give a full account of Harry's story. We can only assume that this meant that most of the information from the graveyard scene in *Goblet of Fire* made it into the final piece.

Comment: It's possible the twin cores thing wasn't mentioned.  Voldemort (you) had to torture that information out of Ollivander. If this was mentioned in the interview you presumably would have known about it earlier

Comment: @user13267 He may well have given a description of the effects of Priori Incantatem without giving a detailed explanation of what Dumbledore told him about *how* it works. A description of events wouldn't have given Voldemort any new information.