# Did the other Death Eaters know about Snape's death at Voldemort's hands?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, severus-snape

Voldemort ordered Lucius Malfoy to go fetch Snape and have him meet the Dark Lord at the Shrieking Shack. Wouldn't Lucius, Narcissa, and others have wondered why Snape didn't rejoin them afterwards? Did Voldemort tell his underlings anything, or did he just lie to them about Snape's whereabouts?

Comment: We don't know, but presumably he did. Voldemort likes control, and one of the ways he gains/maintains that is via information (sharing this news would keep him in control as it's better that he's the one who reveals it than someone else). The other is intimidation (he just offed his potentially most loyal and powerful deputies... no one is safe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voldemort announced it to the assembled crowd during the final duel with Harry, so presumably any remaining Death Eaters were aware of it.

> “Dumbledore was trying to keep the Elder Wand from me! He intended that Snape should be the true master of the wand! But I got there ahead of you, little boy — I reached the wand before you could get your hands on it, I understood the truth before you caught up. **I killed Severus Snape three hours ago**, and the Elder Wand, the Deathstick, the Wand of Destiny is truly mine! Dumbledore’s last plan went wrong, Harry Potter!”

Comment: Actually he is lying. He didn't kill Snape, he ordered Nagini to do it.

Comment: @RalfFriedl https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189951/why-did-dumbledore-tell-everyone-that-voldemort-had-killed-cedric-diggory